# Прогресс бар NodeJS, Mongoose, Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, node-modules

Всем привет!
Прошу помощи, так как не смог найти ничего в гугле)

Что нужно:
Обрабатывать на клиенте процесс загрузки большого xlsx файла, порядка 70к строк.

Пост запрос:

```
router.post('/add', async function (req, res) {
    try {

        await db.connection.db.dropDatabase().then(function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
        await req.files.file.mv('public/xlsx/' + req.files.file.name);
        const resposeData = await parce('./public/xlsx/' + req.files.file.name);


        for (var i = 0; i < resposeData.length; i++) {
            const data = await new Accounts(resposeData[i]);
            await data.save((errors, response) => {
                if (errors) {
                    console.log(errors)
                } else {
                    console.log('saved to database');
                }
            });
        }

        res.json({ message: 'OK!', error: false, count: resposeData.length });


    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: e.message });
    }
});
```

Все работает, так как мне нужно)
Но, на клиенте это не как не отображается.
Помогите, пожалуйста)
Шаблонизатор использую hbs, но это не важно, могу и на jsx перейти

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добрый день! Все очень просто) мне нужно на клиенте (на фронтенде) показывать какой то процесс загрузки, это может быть прогресс бар, загружено ХХ из ХХХ и т.д,  после окончания загрузки в базу, когда все будет загружено, просто убирать этот прогресс бар)